# Laravel5 how to pass array to view

Tags: laravel

I am confuse as how to pass variable from controller to view.  I know there is a lot about this already on stockoverflow but unable to find one that works, please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

CONTROLLER

```
 class StoreController extends Controller

 {
    public function index()
    {
        $store = Store::all(); // got this from database model
        return view('store', $store); 
    }
 {
```

VIEW

```
// try a couple of differnt things nothing works 

print_r($store); 
print_r($store[0]->id);
print_r($id);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
  $store = Store::all(); // got this from database model

  return view('store')->with('store', $store); 
}
```

You've three options in general.

1. `return view('store')->with('store', $store);`
2. `return view('store')->withStore($store);`
3. `return view('store')->with(compact('store'));`

1.Creates a variable named `store` which will be available in your `view` and stores the value in the variable `$store` in it.

2.Shorthand for the above one.

3.Also a short hand and it creates the same variable name as of the value passing one.

Now in your `view` you can access this variable using

`{{ $store->name }}`

it will be same for all 3 methods.

Comment: what is the syntax to call it in view.blade.php? are they all the same?

Comment: Yes, it will be same for all three methods.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    return view('store', ['store' => Store::all()]); 
}
```

Then you can access $store in your review.

Update: If you have your variable defined already in your code and want to use the same name in your view you can also use `compact` method.

Example:

```
public function index()
{
    $store = Store::all();

    return view('store', compact('store')); 
}
```

Comment: Best answer as it doesn't require the extra "with()" method.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me. You can use 'compact' like this:

CONTROLLER:

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
      $store = Store::all(); // 'don't forget' use App\Driver;
      return view('store', compact('store')); 
  }
}
```

Don't forget the library: `use App\Store;`

VIEW:

In the view you have one array with all the data just calling `{{ $store }}`
If you want an specific data use something like:

```
@foreach($store as $data)
   {{ $data->name }}
@endforeach
```

Don't forget to use the "Forms & HTML" of Laravel, here is the link of the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html

Answer (score 3):

Both of the answers provided so far will solve your problem but it's also worth knowing that your original approach of providing `$store` as the second argument to `view()` was very nearly correct. What you were missing is that the argument needs to be an array of the variables you want to pass to the view.

I would probably have gone with `return view('store', compact('store'));` but you could also have used `return view('store', ['store' => $store]);`.

Comment: Thank you, now I know the second arg need to be exactly `key=>value` it's really hard to understand that concept via documentation since I assume array is already in a `key=>value` format.

Comment: No problem. It took me ages when I was learning Laravel to even find out that passing an array as a second argument was even an option. My early code had lots of `return view('view.name')->withSomething($something)->withSomethingElse($somethingElse);`!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    class StoreController extends Controller
 {
    public function index()
    {
        $store = Store::all(); // got this from database model
        return view('store')->withStore($store); 
    }
 }


View :


{{$store->id}}
```

Comment: if it helps you, set my answer as solution ^^

Comment: it works! I was stuck for the longest time,  try to follow the documentation which said `return view('store', $store); ` would you mind explaining `withStore(...)`? I saw other answer that only do `with(...)`?

Comment: Yes, you can use both codes :
return view('view')->withVariable($variable);
or :return view('view')->with('variable', $variable); :)

Answer (score 1):

Even when the other methods work great, the suggested way, is using the compact() helper as a parameter.

```
public function index()
{
  $stores = Store::all(); // got this from database model

  return view('store', compact('stores')); 
}
```

In laravel 5.2 the "with()" method is also used to flash data to your view, the compact helper can handle multiple variables.

Source: Laravel docs and personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

In larval v5.6.3, I am passing Array from Controller to View like this,

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'Welcome to Laravel',
    'services' => ['Web Design', 'Programming', 'SEO']
);

return view('pages.index', compact('data'));
```

And in HTML you can read Array as,

```
@if(count($data['services']) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach($data['services'] as $service)
        <li>{{$service}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same challenge using

```
return view('store', compact('store'));
```

But I was rather using `<?php foreach()... ?>`inside the blade file to test. I changed to `{{ }}` blade syntax and everything worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 6, 7:

```
 class StoreController extends Controller

 {
    public function index()
    {
        $store = Store::all(you can write your filed name here); // got this from database model
        return view('store', compact($store)); 
    }
 {
```