# Laravel passing data from controller to view using sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session, model-view-controller

Somehow, I only managed it to get it working (passing data, arrays from controller to view) using

```
return redirect('whatever')->with('arrayName', $arrayName);
```

inside the view to access it via

```
    @if(!is_null(session('arrayName')))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ session('arrayName')['something'] }} alert-dismissable">
        // more code goes here          
    @endif
```

Now that this appears to be a session, and I'm using this technique in order to pass data in the form of information (such as successfully created XY, deleted, ... and so on) (using the same messages array's name), now and again it happens that information is being displayed on pages where it is not supposed to be (since the above HTML is inside every HTML/blade page in order to always have the opportunity to display messages/alerts) because it is still stored in the session. So it is not only that an old message is shown, it is even a message  I used at a wholly other point inside my application.

I wonder if either the `session()` call is the fault or I need to flush the session (if so, how, and when?) or if I just messed something up about the communication between controller and view, since I have seen (likewise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326115/laravel5-how-to-pass-array-to-view)) that people are using the sole variable name when accessing it inside the view, rather than session(). So is this related, maybe, to an old Laravel version (I'm using the latest) when it was only working back then or something I miss out on?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you use $request->session()->flash('arrayName', 'Task was successful!'); ...

Comment: @Serge how does this play along the function ``redirect()->with()` I used earlier? Please elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the data you're having issues with is data you've manually stored in the session using `session()->put('key', 'value)` or `session(['key' => 'value'])`. When you `put()` data into the session, it stays there until the session expires or it is manually forgotten.

However, if you only want the data to stick around for one response and immediately delete itself after that, you can use the `flash()` method. This is how the `redirect()->with()` functionality works. That data you specify in `with()` is "flashed" to the session, so that it only lasts for one response.

So, you can either change your code to "flash" data to the session when it is only needed for one response, or you will need to update your blade template to manually `forget()` the data after you display it:

```
@if(!is_null(session('arrayName')))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('arrayName')['something'] }} alert-dismissable">

    // more code goes here

    @php
        session()->forget('arrayName')
    @endphp
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not, as I stated in the post, use `session()->put` but only `redirect()->with()` and that's why I wondered so heavily. Some other point, it just said "Added XY successfully" (while it didn't belong there) as a message.