# Routing problem that load my view with only text and url does'nt change

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairly new to the Laravel. I implemented AUTH in laravel with 3 roles.
I've HomeController with index function where I'm checking for what is the  role of the logged in user and depending upon the role I want to load the view. I'm not able to get how do I change the route name from /home to /superadmin.
When I load view it only shows me text but the route is still /home. I know it must have been answered somewhere but nothing is working for me right now.

I've tried this

```
  Redirect::to('superadmin.page1')->with($data);
            return view('superadmin.page1')->with($data);
            return redirect()->route('superadmin');
            return view('superadmin.page1');
```

HomeController.php
//main code

```
try
        {
            if(count($data) < 0)
            {
                return view('user.page1')->with($data);
            }
            else
            {
                //super admin ko pehle check karo , then admin , then user
                $role_array = array();
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $role = $value->role_name;
                        array_push($role_array , $role);
                }

           if (in_array("ROLE_SUPERADMIN", $role_array))
           {
            return view('superadmin.page1')->with($data);
           }
           else if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $role_array))
           {
            return view('admin.page1')->with($data);
           }
           else
           {
            // undefined role found, therefore user 
            return view('user.page1')->with($data);
           }
        }
    }
```

==========

## My route

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/superadmin', 'SuperAdminController@index');

Route::get('/superadminPage1', 'SuperAdminController@page1');
```

I'm getting this as output

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
SuperAdmin Page1
@if (session('status'))
{{ session('status') }}
@endif This is SuperAdmin PAGE1. You must be privileged to be here !
@endsection
```

Comment: You just have shown HomeController code but you have two controllers in routes HomeController and SuperAdminController

Comment: Oh i got the solution , i need to redirect with return redirect()->action('SuperAdminController@index')->with($data);

Comment: @ikdhruw Now how do I get data from from Homecontroller>SuperAdminController to its view OR from superAdminController to its view, i'm getting undefined $data in view

Comment: If you are returning view from the controller just check whether you passing data correctly or not. If you want to use the redirect method use then use named route it makes things much simpler. your SuperAdminController confused me initially

Comment: I'm passing data like this from SuperAdminController - return view('superadmin.home')->with($data); but in view side I'm getting undefined $data

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341826/2669814 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078560/2669814. These answers explained how to pass the data

Comment: On doing this - return view('superadmin.home')->with(["data"=>$data]); I'm getting htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:

Comment: My data is an array which has objects inside it

Comment: It is `->with("data"=>$data)` not `->with(["data"=>$data])`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Comment: I also missed this one this should work `->with('data', $data)`. ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35326267/2669814

Comment: Yes, now working. thanks alot man.